# Error(38,113): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.V_FECHA'

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hey guys i don't know why i'm getting this error...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_VENTAS
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON REGIS_MAYOR
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 

V_PRODUCTO VARCHAR2(100);
V_FECHA DATE;
V_USUARIO VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN
 SELECT DESCRIPCION INTO V_PRODUCTO FROM PRODUCTO;
 SELECT SYSDATE INTO V_FECHA FROM DUAL;
 SELECT USER INTO V_USUARIO FROM DUAL;
 INSERT INTO TRIGGER_VENTAS (PRODUCTO,FECHA,USUARIO) VALUES (:NEW.PRODUCTO,'SE HA GUARDADO NUEVO PRODCUTO'||:NEW.V_FECHA,V_USUARIO);
END;
```

and the error is in new.v_fecha

```
Error(38,113): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.V_FECHA'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is that v_fecha is NOT a column on the table and therefore cannot be references as :new.... It is a local variable and is referenced directly by name. Also since it is defined as a date and you are concatenating to a string it would be better to use to_char on it.

```
insert into trigger_ventas (producto,fecha,usuario) 
     values (:new.producto,'SE HA GUARDADO NUEVO PRODCUTO'|| to_char(v_fecha) ,v_usuario);
```

Further actually specifying the actual date format would be better. For Example

```
insert into trigger_ventas (producto,fecha,usuario) 
     values (:new.producto,'SE HA GUARDADO NUEVO PRODCUTO'|| to_char(v_fecha,'yyyy-mm-dd') ,v_usuario);
```